# Page refresh error on static website in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-static-web-app

I made a static website application in React. localhost is working. but when I upload it to the server, I get a page not found error when I refresh the page on pages other than the home page. What is the solution?

Comment: Sir, Are you uploading react app on Apache Server?

Comment: Where are you upload your project netlify or windows server or linux server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` file on the Server and past below code in the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subdirectory
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you. hepl full. in server public_html folder I created .htaccess and pasted above code.

Comment: very helpful, thank you man! it's very important problem of hosting static react build files in that kind of hostings. i'm using cpanel and these lines of .htaccess codes solved the problem.